# How to fix 'cannot resolve bean sessionFactory' in Spring MVC application?

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

In one of my recent **Spring MVC** project, I face this error while trying to declare **Transaction Manager** in *dispatcher-servlet*, to use **Dao** and **Service**. I've used **IntelliJ Idea 2017.2.5** and use *Maven* to create this project. I hope I've included all the required dependency required for Spring MVC project in **pom.xml**. Here is my source:

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>EMS</name>
<groupId>com.ems</groupId>
<artifactId>ems</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!--Spring Core-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring Web-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring MVC-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring Context-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--MySQL Connector-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring JDBC-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jackson-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--GSON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is **dispatcher-servlet.xml:**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ems" />

<!--Initiating Database File-->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<!--Mapping static resource (i.e: css, js) in project-->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resource/**" location="/resource/" />

<!--Database source definition-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- <property name="annotatedClasses">-->
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.ems.models</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

And here is **web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<display-name>Employee Management System</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I fix that issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bean definition names are not properly aligned.

You've defined `LocalSessionFactoryBean` as `hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory`.  You then specify that your `HibernateTransactionManager` references a session factory bean using the name `sessionFactory`, which leads to your problem.

Please either change your `HibernateTransactionManager` definition to reference a session factory named `hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory` or alter the name you give to your session factory bean to be `sessionFactory`.